# Запись значений из одного словаря в другой при различиях в именах ключей

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, словари

Есть два словаря:

```
dict_1 = {'Петя Петров':0, 'Иван Иванов': 0, 'С.C. Сидоров': 0}
dict_2 = {'Петров': 1, 'Иванов': 2, 'Шпак':3}
```

Нужно значения из dict_2 записать в соответствующие значения dict_1. Если в первом словаре отсутствует соответствующий ключ, нужно известить об этом. Узнав, что в конструкции if/else слова if и else необязательно должны быть с равными отступами, попробовал написать следующий код:

```
for k_2 in dict_2:
    for k_1 in dict_1:
        if k_2 in k_1:
            dict_1[k_1] += dict_2[k_2]
            break       
    else:
        print(k_2, 'не найден')

print(dict_1)
```

Результат:

```
Шпак не найден
{'Петя Петров': 1, 'Иван Иванов': 2, 'С.C. Сидоров': 0}
```

---

Вроде работает. Хочу узнать мнение профессионалов, имеет ли данный код право на существование? Какие существуют еще способы решения моей задачи?

Comment: `dict((k1,dict_2[k2]) if k2 in k1 else (k1, 'не найден') for k1, k2 in zip(dict_1, dict_2))`

Comment: if k_2 in k_1: Здесь вы проверяте входит ли ключ из первого словаря в название ключа второго словаря. Т.е если во втором словаре есть будет ключ 'П', а в первом есть ключ 'Петя Петров', то всё равно ваш код проёдет и не выдаст 'не найден'. Так и нужно? Или нужно чтобы ключи из словарей полностью совпадали?

Comment: В `dict_2` могут встречаться только фамилии (слово на второй позиции)?

Comment: @Dimabytes, нужно, чтобы ключ из второго словаря входил в название ключа первого словаря. Полностью совпадать они не должны.

Comment: @MaxU, необязательно. В первом словаре могут встречаться ключи в виде 'имя фамилия' или 'фамилия имя'

Comment: в случае с однофамильцами будет не вполне корректная работа такого кода

Answer (score 1):

Попытка переписать алгоритм привела к большем количеству строк и уменьшение "сахарности", в общем, спорное решение:

```
for k_2 in dict_2:
    found = False

    for k_1 in dict_1:
        if k_2 in k_1:
            dict_1[k_1] += dict_2[k_2]
            found = True
            break

    if not found:
        print(k_2, 'не найден')
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вынести условия в отдельный словарь соответствий, при его создании можно более разветвлённую логику "прикрутить":

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
dict_1 = {'Петя Петров':0, 'Иван Иванов': 0, 'С.C. Сидоров': 0}
dict_2 = {'Петров': 1, 'Иванов': 2, 'Шпак': 3}

dict_3 = dict([(k1, k2) for k2 in dict_2 for k1 in dict_1 if k2 in k1])

for k in dict_1:
    try:
        print dict_2[dict_3[k]]
    except KeyError:
        print 'для ', k, 'значение не найдено'
```

Comment: `...не думайте о мнении профессионалов...` обычно всегда полезно узнать мнение коллег :)

Comment: спс, не сразу понял, что хотел автор